# Calling different environment configurations at runtime using Katalon

Tags: c#, .net, slowcheetah, katalon-studio

I have something in .net visual studio called slowcheetah that allows me to store multiple app.configs for environment URLs and call them depending on the test environment I'm running against for my selenium tests. I can toggle this at runtime.

I'm wondering if Katalon can do the same.

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables (or "execution profiles", as they are called in Katalon Studio versions 5.4+): 
https://docs.katalon.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=13697476.

For details, tips and tricks on the topic, there is a interesting discussion on the Katalon forums: 
https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/5780/katalon-properties-file-and-jvm-system-property-katalon-user-home#latest.

Hope this helps.